# What book is this comic page apparently referring to Alex Jones from?

Tags: story-identification

Someone posted this page on Reddit wondering if it was referring to a well known media personality. Unfortunately, they did not share what book it was from. Anyone know?

[image]

Comment: A model spaceship does not make this SFnal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[InvestiGators: Agents of S.U.I.T.](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/investigators-john-patrick-green/1142680387)* by John Patrick Green, Christopher Hastings, and Pat Lewis

[image: Front cover of InvestiGators: Agents of S.U.I.T.]

> At S.U.I.T. headquarters, Cilantro the Chameleon finally gets what she’s been waiting for: a field assignment. Only…it’s literally out in the middle of a field, and her orders are so vague, she can hardly tell what she’s supposed to be investigating. But as she begins to uncover a sheep-led worker’s rights revolt and an alien invasion conspiracy—not to mention a spooky haunting at the abandoned S.U.I.T. field outpost—Cilantro steps into her own V.E.S.T. as a valued member of the S.U.I.T. team. From InvestiGators mastermind John Patrick Green, the world of S.U.I.T. has never been more fun!

I was about to give up on this one when a search for `comic book alien visitation sheep farm` turned up the Barnes & Noble page, which has a picture of part of that page, and then the following page, from which I recognized the chameleon and cat characters.

[image: Image of the following page]

It is apparently a spin-off of [*InvestiGators*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/InvestiGators) (warning, TV Tropes page). *InvestiGators*, and by extension *Agents of S.U.I.T.*, is definitely sci-fi with fantastic inventions, robot duplicates, and enlarging rays.